# Dynamic Process parameter adjustment in Semiconductor manufacturing data

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, classification

I have process parameter data from semiconductor manufacturing.and requirement is to suggest  what could be the best parameter adjustment to be made to process parameter to get better yield ie best path for high yield. what machine learning /Statistical models best suits this requirement

Note:I have thought of using decision tree which can give us best path for high yield.

Would like to know it any other methods that can be more efficient

data is like
lotno x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 yield(%)

<95% yield is considered as 0 and >95% as 1

Comment: the question is not very clear as you wrote it. Are you trying to do feature selection where the optimal feature set is the one that will get you the highest accuracy?

Comment: i have already selected the features.the problem is if i have a new data (lotno x1,x2..x5) i need to suggest what  adjustment (+or-some value) to these parameters will give me best yield.this has be done by looking at training data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of the question here, but as a former semiconductor process engineer, here is how I look at the yield improvement approach - perspective.

Process Development.
DOE:  Typically,  I would run structured DOEs to understand my process (#4). I would first identify "potential" 'factors', and run various "screening" experiments to identify statistical significance.  With the goal basically here to identify the most statistically significant (and for that matter, least significant) factors. So these are inherently simple experiments, low # of "levels" which don't target understanding of the curvature of the response surface, they just look for magnitude change of response vs factor.   Generally, I am most concerned with 'Process' factors,  but it is important to recognize that the influence of variable inputs can come from more than just "machine knobs' as example.  Variable can arise from 1) People,  2) Environment (moisture, temp, etc),  3) consumables (used in the process),  4) Equipment (is 40 psi on this tool really 40 psi and the same as 40 psi on a different tool) 4) Process variable settings.

With the most statistically significant factors, I would run more elaborate DOE using the major factors and analyze this data to develop a model. There are generally more 'levels' used here to allow for curvature insight of the response surface via the analysis.  There are many types of well known standard experimental design structures here. And there is software such as JMP that is specifically set up to do this analysis.

From here, the idea would be to generate a model in the form of Response = F (Factors).  That allows you to essentially optimize the response based upon these factors where the response is a reflection of your yield criteria.

From here, the engineer would typically execute confirmation runs with optimized factors to confirm optimized response.

Note that the software analysis typically allows for the engineer to illuminate any run order dependence. The execution of the DOE is typically performed in a randomized cell fashion.   (Each 'cell' is a set of conditions for the experiment). Similarly the experiments include some level of repetition to gauge 'repeatability' of the 'system'. This inclusion can be explicit (run the same cell twice),  but there is also some level of repeatability inherent in the design as well since you are running multiple cells, albeit at difference settings. But generally, the experiment includes explicitly repeated cells.

And finally there is the concept of manufacturability, which includes constraints of time, cost, physical limits, equipment capability, etc.  (The ideal process works great, but it takes 10 years, costs 1 million dollars and requires projected settings outsides the capability of the tool.)

Since you have manufacturing data, hopefully, you have the data that captures the other types of factors as well  (1,2,3), so you should specifically analyze the data to try to identify such effects.  This is typically done as A vs B comparisons.  Person A vs B,  Tool A vs B, Consumable A vs B, Consumable lot A vs B,  Summer vs Winter,  etc.
Basically, there are all sorts of comparisons you could envision here and check for statistically differences across two sets of populations.

A comment on response:  What is the yield criteria?  You should know this in order to formulate the model.  For semiconductors, we have both line yield (process yield) but there is also device yield.  I assume for your work, you are primarily concerned with line yield.  So minimizing variability in the factors (from 1,2,3,4) to achieve the desired response (target response(s) with minimal variability) is the primary goal.

APC (Advanced Process Control).
In  many cases, there is significant trending that results from whatever reason;  crappy tool control (the tool heats up),  crappy consumable (the target material wears,  the polishing pad wears, the chemical bath gets loaded, whatever), and so the idea here is how to adjust the next batch/lot/wafer based upon the history of what came prior. Either improve the manufacturing to avoid/minimize this trending (run order dependence) or adjust process to accommodate it to achieve the desired response.

Time for lunch,  hope this helps...if you post on the specific process module type, and even equipment and consumables, I might be able to provide more insight.